# How to send a rest PUT request in angular passing body

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to send a rest request to a web server, I am using this code :

```
var getData = function(...) {
    return $http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: getStatistics,
      headers: {
        'loginId': ...,
        'token': ...,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: {"...":"...","...":"...","...":"...","...":"...",
             "...":"....","....":"...",
             "datefrom":"2017-01-01","dateto":"2017-10-20"}
    }).then(function(result){
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.data);
        alert(result.data);
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

The problem is that I am receiving error 400 bad request, What should I do?

The request works on Postman With this structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBrwF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbQuO.jpg

Should it be a problem of how Am I passing the data object ?

That's how I implemented the $httpParamSerializerJQLike, it it Correct?

```
app.factory('statistics', function($http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
var getData = function(loginId,token,id,dataInizio,dataFine,periodo,selezione) {
    // Angular $http() and then() both return promises themselves

    var data = '{"datefrom":"2017-01-01","dateto":"2017-10-20"}';

    alert(data);
    return $http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: getStatistics,
      headers: {
        'loginId': loginId,
        'token': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: { 'data': $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)}
    }).then(function(result){
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.data);
        alert(result.data);
        return result.data;
    });
};

return { getData: getData };
});
```

Comment: You're sending JSON as the request body, but claim it's application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Comment: Can u write an example here, because I tryed it, but It seam not to work

Comment: No. Instead. Edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: @JBNizet Added the code

Comment: It should be `data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)`. Not `data: { 'data': $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)}`. Just like the example in the documentation.

Comment: But the param in the body of postman is called data...anyway I will try

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that. This is a bit messy: instead of sending a JSON body, you're sending an x-www-form-urlencoded body, but it contains a single parameter named data, containing JSON. Why are you designing an API this way is a mystery to me, but anyway, you thus need `data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({data: angular.toJson(data)})`

Comment: Thank you... you solved this problem. I am not the api designer, and I am confused as you for how he decided to designing it. I will mark as solved !!

Comment: I can't mark a comment as correct answer... so pleas add an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're sending an x-www-form-urlencoded body, but it contains a single parameter named data, containing JSON.

You thus need

```
data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({data: angular.toJson(data)})
```